# How to add opencv DLL on Windows to QTCreator project?

Tags: qt, opencv, dll, qt-creator

I've built opencv and added these lines to .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.4.1/build/install/include

LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_core341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_highgui341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_imgcodecs341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_imgproc341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_features2d341d.lib
```

now if I start the project, it links successfully but fails to start:

```
Starting C:\Users\steve\Documents\build-qttest4-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\qttest4.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
```

Can I somehow tell QTCreator to add DLL files to put opencv DLL files to **build-qttest4-Desktop_Qt_5_11_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (which doesn't match top google search tutorial):

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv-3.4.1/build/install/include
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_core341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_highgui341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_imgcodecs341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_imgproc341d.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv-3.4.1\build\LIB\Debug\opencv_features2d341d.lib
LIBS += -L"C:/opencv-3.4.1/build/bin/Debug"
```

and don't forget to run **Build->Run qmake**.

Comment: And of course LIBS+= -L "" is the most simple solution

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to use DLL in some Windows Application

1. Use WinAPI LoadLibrary function and  GetProcAddress function.
2. Set inside a Qt PRO file a location of LIB file that will tell to application that binary code is in YourLibraryName.DLL. But when you run debugger, application doesn't know where is DLL. One of possible solutions is to put full path to opencv DLL folder to PATH environment variable in windows Control Panel